# Parsing Symbolic Equations to Sympy functions

Tags: python, parsing, expression, sympy, equation

I am trying to pass [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23uK5.png) in my code when i copy and paste this as text it looks like this `∑(i=1,n)(a+m*x*(i)-y*(i))^2`.

but it does not work.

following is my code which is working with a different syntax:

```
from sympy import symbols,sympify,solve,Eq,Symbol

from sympy import symbols,Eq,sympify,summation
expr = **('summation((m * x*(i) + a - y*(i))^2, (i, 0, n))')**
Eq1 = Eq(sympify(expr))
print(Eq1)
values = {2001,10,2,3,5}
arr_symbols = list(Eq1.free_symbols)
print(arr_symbols)
Method1(arr_symbols,values,expr)

def Method1(arr_symbols,Values,expr):
    from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve, pprint, integrate, sympify
    z = symbols('z')
    Formula = Eq(sympify(expr),z)
    print(Formula)
    index = 0
    for i in Values:
        Formula = Formula.subs(arr_symbols[index],i)
        index+=1
    print(solve(Formula))
```

but what i want to do is to use `∑(i=1,n)(a+m*x*(i)-y*(i))^2` and ask sympy to convert it for me.

Comment: It is not clear what data you are working with. Do you have values of x and y? m? a? What variables do the values in `values` correspond to?

Comment: yes the values replace the variables x,y,m,a respectively but thats not the issue here.
the problem is when i pass "∑24_(i=0)^n▒〖(a+mx(i)-y(i))^2" as my expression, it fails calling it syntax error. i want a method to convert "∑24_(i=0)^n▒〖(a+mx(i)-y(i))^2" to 
"summation((m * x*(i) + a - y*(i))^2, (i, 0, n))"
this is the way sympy understands the expression

Comment: I don't think SymPy can parse such a thing. It recognizes code but not something like a summation sign as a function. What are you trying to do? If you are passing only a single value for x and y then a summation isn't needed.

Comment: this summation is just one example of what i want to do.
i have many more expressions like this with various symbols and i want to find a way to convert them into python understanding through python code.
the expressions i have will all be dynamic application will be reading them from an excel written by the end user and an end user wont write it in the form for python to understand he will write the formula as they write regularly

Comment: if sympy cant do it maybe there's another library which can. i have been stuck on this for 2 days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it cannot be done.
we have to pass latex code.

Answer (score 1):

SymPy can represent this equation, but it can only parse Python. You might be able to write extensions to its parser to handle this sort of thing (see https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html). It should be possible in principle, although it might not be straightforward. I would only recommend doing this the syntax of your expressions is already very close to Python. If it isn't (and it looks like it isn't), it would be better to a real parsing library like ANTLR to build up a grammar for your expressions. You can then use that to parse into SymPy (see for example how the [`sympy.parsing.latex`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/tree/master/sympy/parsing/latex) module is written).

I don't know if there is pre-existing library in Python that handles your types of expressions. I'm not aware of any. At best you might be able to find a grammar that someone has already written, so you don't have to write it yourself.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer but i have already checked the latex parsing it does not work for these kind of expressions. but i am still looking for a library which can help me with my problem

Comment: I am not saying the LaTeX parser can parse these expressions. It cannot. Rather I am saying you will need to build your own parser, and looking at how the LaTeX parser is built can give you some hints on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are, given `a`, `m` and values for `x` and `y` and are trying to compute the sum of the squares of the residuals, then it would be better to write a function that does that or do something like this:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [4, 7, 11]
>>> a = 2
>>> m = 5
>>> sum((a + m*xi - yi)**2 for xi, yi in zip(x, y))
70
```

Comment: this summation is just one example of what i want to do.
i have many more expressions like this with various symbols and i want to find a way to convert them into python understanding through python code.
the expressions i have will all be dynamic application will be reading them from an excel written by the end user and an end user wont write it in the form for python to understand he will write the formula as they write regularly

Comment: if sympy cant do it maybe there's another library which can. i have been stuck on this for 2 days now.